# How to export Windows network certificate with private key for use with Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, certificate, private-key

For context, I need to connect to a network which requires a certificate to connect. The program to install the certificate is only available on windows and Mac. I successfully installed the certificate into a windows virtual machine and want to export it in a way that it can be used with Linux.

I know the name of the certificate and I assume it has a private key because on windows you only need the certificate to connect (no username or password).
I have tried using the built-in exporter in Certificate Manager but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are ways to mark keys as non-exportable when you first add them. That's standard practice for system certs that authenticate a whole machine to the network. I'm pretty sure there are security tools out there that can still extract them, but I doubt there is any built-in way.

Comment: @Spiff I'd still be interested if you know a way or anyone else on here does.